# Multilanguage table design problem

Tags: database, database-design, schema, multilingual

I am having an implementation issue with this basic multilang design.

**Table content**

```
content_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,  
lang_id int(5) NOT NULL,   
word varchar (500) NOT NULL,  
created datatime,
```

Now the issue is with implementing this. I assume in the application i am declaring each word on the page with the content_id like 1,2,3,4,5... where 1 = "Hello" 2 = "Welcome to xxxxx" etc. Right? So the problem is I give "Hello" = 1 in the code. So in the table it is like this
1, 23 (for english), Hello.

But now if i have a Spanish session, how will i find "Hello" in the table? Because I hardcoded 1 in the code to be "Hello" so the system will always lookup this up and find the english text. The only work around i see is to have separate tables per language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make lang_id and content_id a composite primary key. You'll end up with data that looks like this:

```
1         Hello            1
1         Hola             2
2         Thanks           1
2         Gracias          2
2         Danke            3
```

You might even want to break out the English translation into a separate table to make it easier for you as the developer (since you speak English)...then you know that WordId 1 is, canonically, "Hello". Foreign key to language table, obviously. If you do this, you might want a surrogate key for the primary key as well...that simplifies updates.

Comment: I would recommend NOT to use one language as your "default" language which is than translated, but instead use IDs (they do not have to be numerical!) which map (together with a language ID) to a language entry. For example your Hello which is displayed on the homepage could have the ID "homepage.greeting".

Comment: Composite PK is for the database but i still need to reference it in the code and as far as i know we cant do that in the code? I have to still declare Hello = 1 in the code unless you are telling me i can declar Hello = (1,1)? And does this schema work for this usecase: "If no language translation is found then it defaults to english for that word"

Comment: Well, give it whatever canonical name you want - my point is that rather than having to query the value for the English language value you wanted, you could instead join to the table that contained the developer friendly identifier.

Comment: Paul - what is the benefit with your way?

Comment: @JohnnyK - see the exchange between me and Paul. What we're getting at here is that you have another table which defines canonically (that is, without respect to the language aspect of this) what you're trying to retrieve, e.g., "HomePageGreeting". So you would have a query that was something like this: `SELECT LocalizedWord FROM LocalizedContent LC JOIN CanonicalContent CC ON LC.WordId = CC.ID WHERE CC.Title = 'HomepageGreeting' AND LC.LanguageId = 2`, or replace CC.Title = 'HomepageGreeting' with CC.Id = 1.

Comment: Let me think about this and see how it maps out.